# iOS UITableView reloadData only refreshes table the second time I call my reload function

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, reloaddata

Here is my reload function

```
- (void) reloadTable:(id)sender
{   
    NSLog(@"Reload Table");
    NSLog(@"%@",[appDelegate queryList]);
    [self.driverTable reloadData];
    [self.driverTable setNeedsLayout];
    [self.driverTable setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Here is where I call it after receiving data from the webservice

```
if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Response"]) {
    Response = NO;
    LookupView *lookupView = [[LookupView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LookupView" bundle:nil];
    [lookupView reloadTable:self];
}
```

Problem I have right now is after I do a search by pressing a find button and receive the data.  The table does not refresh with the new data.  If I call the same function again by pressing the find button again the table reloads.  Now I know the data is there because I print the array out before I call the table reload.

Any ideas why?

Comment: why do you need setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay?  UITableViews aren't in need of redraw, they handle that themselves at reload time.

Comment: oh, I was just researching for solutions here, some people with similar problems mentioned this so I was just trying

Comment: Delete those things method mentioned by @CodaFi .It doesn't belong to be there.

Comment: @DanielChen You said your data is reloading second time, when you press find button.So is that reloadTable: method getting called or not in first time? If it is called, then what is console output you got for printed the array??

Comment: I believe it is getting called, as I am printing the list out when that method is getting called.  And even the first time I click that button the list get printed with expected data list.  And I removed the lines mentioned by @CodaFi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have run into the same issue.  Per Apple's documentation, reloadData "should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows."  A workaround I have used is to delay the call to reloadData so that it is not immediately after updating table.  Try this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayedReloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

at the appropriate place with the following implementation of delayReloadData

```
 -(void)delayedReloadData{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

A negative side affect I have see from this approach is that if the table row is visible there is a short delay before it shows its content.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018754/why-reloaddata-shouldnt-be-called-on-methods-that-delete-insert-rows) question can count as a follow up to @bobnoble's answer

Answer (score 0):

I found out you are doing XML parsing by seeing that `elementName` in your `if loop`. Why you need to `load a NIB file` in your parsing code. What is the use of it? You can just call your `reloadTable:` method just like this.

```
[self reloadTable:self];
```

You are populating your tableView using some array in your `app delegate` file. So did you initialized your delegate in your ViewController?

Comment: Yes you are right, I am populating the array that contains the data for the table using the app delegate. Once I know all the information is loaded into the array I use the app delegate to call the refresh table function in the view controller of the table.